# How can I block unauthenticated user use my Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

My approach to block unauthenticated user to use my Firebase Cloud Functions is to add this boilerplate code in the beginning of all functions. Please note that I am using Callable Function `functions.https.onCall`, **NOT** HTTP Function `functions.https.onRequest`

```js
if (!context.auth) {
    // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "failed-precondition",
      "The function must be called while authenticated."
    );
  }
```

Is there a better way to block unauthenticated user so that invalid call can NOT even invoke my function?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firebase Authentication and also use custom claims, using `context` auth might be easiest way to do check that. Alternatively, you can allow only `allAuthenticatedUsers` to invoke the Cloud Function as shown below:

[image]

However, in this case you'll have to add and verify that Authorization header manually. You can use `gcloud auth print-identity-token` to get your token (different that Firebase Auth's ID token) for testing.

Comment: if I understand correctly, your approach works only for account in IAM, but NOT the Firebase user, who does not associated with IAM principal, right?

Comment: @CupidChan that's correct but the function won't invoke at first place. If you want to use Firebase auth then you'll have to continue using `context.auth` (function invocation is counted),

Comment: Thanks @Dharmaraj, but that's exactly why I asked this question: Is there any other way to NOT using context.auth, but block the innovation for all unauthenticated users.